# Time Capsule Wireless spot give enormous latency

Tags: router, lan, adsl, wan

Noticed, that after a day or a two of use of home network I getting enormous ping time to ADSL modem. Usually it's about 2 ms. But when problem appears - it's 500++ ms.

After Time Capsule rebooting problem disappears (but ADSL modem rebooting don't help).

Also noticed interesting thing: if I disconnect ADSL modem lan cable from Time Capsule and connect it to my laptop for at least 1 minute and then connect it back to Time Capsule - problem disappears also!

In some groups I'd found advice to connect LAN cable to other Ethernet ports then WAN. Dith doesn't works!

Pls, help me, don't have idea what to do due to lack of settings in Time Machine preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if there is a loop in your setup, cable going out one port and into another. Also you should check whether you have DHCP running on your Time Capsule or not and if it is also running on your ADSL modem.

If both have DHCP enabled, and you connected the cable to the normal ports on the Time Capsule (not being the WAN port) then they're gonna have a fight.

Depending on how your DSL modem is configured, bridge- or router-mode you need to set your Time Capsule to either router or AP (access point) mode.

See here for instructions and screenshots: http://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/networking/configuring-an-airport-extreme-for-nat-only-mode/

For this to work you need updated firmware! These options where changed somewhere in the past year (2013).

If your modem has DHCP enabled: use "Off (bridge mode)" which is AP mode.

If your modem gives your only the public IP address:  "DHCP and NAT" which is router mode.

If your modem does work as a router but doesn't automatically give IP addresses: set a fixed IP address on your Time Capsule and set it to "DHCP Only" which is AP mode with DHCP.

Comment: Chris, my TC works in bridge mode initially. So - what do you recommend?

Comment: Does your mac start a time machine backup after a few minutes?

Comment: You mean — very often?

Comment: Yes, my Time Machine backup (although to USB connected drive) runs very 15 mins I think. I can imagine that it will take a lot of bandwidth and just congest your network.. Especially if you have a bunch of big new files..

Comment: No, it's not related to backups schedule. It's just slow - that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some device (usually some tv receiver/emitter) on your network that is flooding/broadcasting the network with multicast frames/packets. The Apple Time Capsule is trying to replay these packets to your devices through WiFi, thus saturating the bandwidth.

Check if you have an "IGMP Snooping" snooping option in your Time Capsule.

If you have two set-up boxes from your provider, one for tv, one for internet, usually having a direct cable between the two (no router, no switch) should disable multicasting on the whole network.